# How to do multiple pattern replaces with sed

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed

This is my file example.txt

```
{foo}
{bar}
{f}oo}
{ba{r}
{fo}o}
{b{ar}
```

I want this result:

```
<div class="id">foo</div>
<div class="id">bar</div>
<div class="id">f}oo</div>
<div class="id">ba{r</div>
<div class="id">fo}o</div>
<div class="id">b{ar</div>
```

i have command in notepad++ to get result as above

```
([}]\r\n)|(\r\n[{])|(^[{])|([}]$)
(?1}</div>)(?2<div class="id">{)(?3<div class="id">{)(?4}</div>)
```

I tried with this `sed` command

```
sed -i 's@}\r\n@</div>@g' *.html
```

which left my file unchanged.  How to do this correctly with `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following `sed` command with specific regex pattern:

```
sed -ri 's/\{(.+)\}/<div class="id">\1<\/div>/g' testfile
```

`-r` option allows extended regular expressions

---

`\{(.+)\}` - matches any characters enclosed with curly braces `{}`

`\1` - points to the first captured group which is `(.+)`

Comment: hello tanks for answer, but your command not work to me, i have edit my question above, to replace
    {

and

    }

only with matches top lines and end lines

Comment: @kijiroluduatiga, check my update, it works for your new input example

Answer (score 1):

How about using two simple expressions, like this:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/^./<div class="id">/;s/.$/<\/div>/' file
```

- replaces the first character with `<div class="id">` and the last character with `</div>` leaving the rest of the line intact.
- no need for any capture groups

Gives this output:

```
<div class="id">foo</div>
<div class="id">bar</div>
<div class="id">f}oo</div>
<div class="id">ba{r</div>
<div class="id">fo}o</div>
<div class="id">b{ar</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sed -e 's/{\(.*\)}/<div class="id">\1<\/div>/'
```

sed is line-oriented, so you won't find `\n` in a record (unless you're using some of the advanced commands).

Comment: how to replace to many bracket inside { }, example {f}oo{bar} and i want result <div class="id">f}oo{bar</div>, so only replace bracket in matched top line and new line, use ^{ and }$ not working on sed

Answer (score 0):

It may interest you to user **Perl**

```
$ cat file
{foo}
{bar}
{f}oo}
{ba{r}
{fo}o}
{b{ar}
$
$ perl -lpe 's/^.(.*?).$/<div class="id">\1<\/div>/' file
$ 
<div class="id">foo</div>
<div class="id">bar</div>
<div class="id">f}oo</div>
<div class="id">ba{r</div>
<div class="id">fo}o</div>
<div class="id">b{ar</div>
```

---

It also has **save in place** like `sed` with `-i`